# How to set files load order with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

The files directory is:

```
$ cd src/lib/Rpc/
$ ls
a.php b.php c.php
```

Then, I write the line in `composer.json` file:

```
autoload: {
  psr-4: {
    Rpc\\: src/lib/Rpc/
  }
}
```

Now I want to load the file which it will be loaded the first when load `Rpc` lib.

Because the file needs to set global function, the content of file:

```
<?php
Rpc\Chan::setDefaultVar();
```

So, how should I write the `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, lets do this...

**a) Syntax of your `composer.json` file is invalid.**

You can check the syntax of your `composer.json` file by using the command `composer validate composer.json` on the CLI. It will give you some details about the missing properties and the syntax in general.

You minimal `composer.json` file should include a name, description and a license - but `validate` will tell you.

I've fixed your `composer.json` syntax and added the missing properties - to get you started.

```
{
    "name": "thinkerou/rpc-project",
    "description": "description for my rpc-project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Rpc\\": "src/lib/Rpc/"
      }
    }
}
```

**b) The Autoloading problem**

Its a bit hard to understand your question, because of the language barrier, but
i understand it like this: you want to load one file of your library always, because it uses a static function to initialize some values, right?

I would suggest to use the `files` autoloading mechanism in this case. It will require certain files explicitly on every request (!). (Its often used, when  your package includes PHP functions that cannot be autoloaded by PHP, but should work in this case, too.)

Example:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["autoload_this_file_on_every_request.php"]
    }
}
```

---

So, in the end the complete example with "PSR-4 autoloading" for the classes of your library and "files autoloading" for one specific file would look like this:

```
{
    "name": "thinkerou/rpc-project",
    "description": "description for my rpc-project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Rpc\\": "src/lib/Rpc/"
      },
      "files": ["src/lib/Rpc/autoload_this_file_on_every_request.php"]
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how to set the order of autoloading packages. The -1 was for nitpicking remark a)

Comment: Really? Come contribte to Composer and get really nitpicked with greetings from Alcohol. Anyway.. --- Didn't i answer the question? The classes in the "files" section are loaded before `psr-4`. I don't see another way to ensure that the file is loaded always first. And to nitpick a bit more: the whole approach in the question isn't very good: static, global... care to downvote twice?